# Strange `Collection was modified` exception though it never gets modified

Tags: c#, list, multithreading, thread-safety

Why do I get `Collection was modified` exception if I have a predefined collection and its values are accessed and updated by index only. No thread deletes or adds items to the collection. The exception happens on the line `var values = new List<double> { amount.Values[0], amount.Values[1] };`

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SkipIterator>d__31`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at MyProject.Exensions.ToFixed(Amount amount) in ...\Amount.cs:line 43 ...
```

**CODE**

```
private List<double> _currentAmount = new List<double>(...);
public async Task<Amount> GetAmount(bool fromCache = true)
{
   if(!fromCache)
   {
       _currentAmount = await _service.GetAmount(); 
   }
   
   return new Amount(_currentAmount).ToFixed(); 
}

// Called every 100ms by other thread
private void OnAmountChanged(AmountChangedEventArgs args)
{
    _currentAmount[args.Index] = args.Value;
    AmountChanged?.Invoke(new Amount(_currentAmount));
}

public static Amount ToFixed(this Amount amount)
{
    var values = new List<double> { amount.Values[0], amount.Values[1] };
    values.Add(amount.Values[2] * 0.1);
    values.AddRange(amount.Values.Skip(3));

    return new Amount(values);
}

public sealed class Amount
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<double> Values { get; }

    public Amount(IList<double> values)
    {
        Values = new ReadOnlyCollection<double>(values);
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from collections which are not designed to be used in multithreaded environment? Use `lock` or other containers which handles concurrency. `_currentAmount[args.Index] = args.Value;` changes collection with all UB and all possible exceptions.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, but "changes collection" only means when an item added or removed, not when a value is modified by index, doesn't it?

Comment: Please post an MCVE. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Everything in sources. It changes [version](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L164) of `List`. Use Array instead.

Comment: From my side, because you have used non concurrent collection in multithreading environment. It is always Undefined Behaviour.  You do not need to check sources, if collection is not not ready for multithreading, always guard with synchronisation techniques (read and write). `lock` is simplest and working way. Downvoted (removed) because, there are a lot of answers on SO for such situation and just googling will move you in the right way.

Comment: Most likely the exception is thrown in the line `values.AddRange(amount.Values.Skip(3));`, not in the line that you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're invalidating the iterator by modifying the list. In comments, you said:

> but "changes collection" only means when an item added or removed, not when a value is modified by index, doesn't it?

But no, that's not what it means. From the [documentation of `List<T>.GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getenumerator?view=net-7.0) (emphasis mine):

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, **modifying**, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and the next call to `MoveNext` or `IEnumerator.Reset` throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

This is easy to demonstrate in a minimal example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var list = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 };
foreach (var element in list)
{
    list[1] = 5;
}
```

That throws an `InvalidOperationException` exception, contrary to your expectations.

Comment: I think that the term "iterator" has a distinct meaning in C#. It's not the same with an enumerator.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: No, it really is the same concept - there's a reason why an "iterator block" is how you return an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerator<T>`. It's far from uncommon to call the result of `GetEnumerator` an iterator - it's "something that iterates". The docs for `IEnumerator<T>` start with "Supports a simple iteration over a generic collection." (I personally prefer the way that Java calls the types `Iterable` and `Iterator`. There's no need to introduce a second term, when "iterates" is a more common prose description.)

Comment: OK, fair enough. Personally I use the term iterator only for methods that contain `yield return` statements.

Comment: @JonSkeet, so even using a thread-safe container like `ConcurrentBag` won't help, since it's implemented internally probably the same way, right?

Comment: @theateist: No, because, from the documentation of `ConcurrentBag.GetEnumerator`: "The enumeration represents a moment-in-time snapshot of the contents of the bag. It does not reflect any updates to the collection after GetEnumerator was called. The enumerator is safe to use concurrently with reads from and writes to the bag."